# Boto3 get Elasticache ARN

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to automate the creation and destruction of services in AWS.
the destruction is tag-based, in order to use `boto3.client('elasticache').list_tags_for_resource()`
I need to supply its ARN of the cache-cluster and it's not part of the describing method `boto3.client('elasticache').describe_cache_clusters()`
like in other resources (DynamoDB or RDS for example)
is there a different way to get the ARN (except of assembling it manually) or an alternate way to iterate over the existing cache-clusters and check the tags?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/IAM.Overview.html), You can generate ARN with a format below.

> arn:aws:elasticache:region:account-id:cluster:resource-name

Example:

> arn:aws:elasticache:us-west-2:0123456789:cluster:myCluster

or

> arn:aws:elasticache:us-west-2:0123456789:snapshot:mySnapshot

Refer links:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/IAM.Overview.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was aiming to find the ARN without assembling it manually.

Comment: AWS sometimes miss useful information in API. In a lot of cases, we have to create ARN via the provided format.