# Reference arn of a Elasticache cluster in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache, aws-policies

I would like to reference the arn of a "going-to-be-created" Redis ElastiCache cluster in a cloud formation template. 
This is the ElasticacheCluster template (tested and working in cloudFormation)

```
ElasticacheCluster:
Type: AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster
Properties:
  AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: 'true'
  Engine: redis
  CacheNodeType: cache.t2.micro
  NumCacheNodes: '1'
  VpcSecurityGroupIds:
  - Fn::GetAtt:
    - ElastiCacheSecurityGroup
    - GroupId
  CacheSubnetGroupName:
    Ref: ElastiCacheSubnetGroup
```

I cut on the other staff like subnetgroup and security group because it is also not relevant here. I should grant access to the Cluster to another resource with an Access Policies here what I was trying:

```
AccessPolicies:
    Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
    - Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        AWS: "*"
      Action: es:*
      Resource: !GetAtt ElasticacheCluster.Arn
    - Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        AWS: "*"
      Action: es:*
      Resource: !GetAtt ElasticacheCluster.Arn
      Condition:
        IpAddress:
          aws:SourceIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I saw this:

> the !GetAtt ElasticacheCluster.Arn for the resource entry

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737067/retrieve-the-arn-of-a-lambda-function-from-a-cloudformation-stack) but seems not to be working in this case since !GetAtt is returning a fixed set of attributes and ARN is not one of them (as suggested by @Anton in the comments. 
I also saw [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59918221/boto3-get-elasticache-arn) that could solve the issue but I would prefer a not-harcoded-solution being not dependent on things like region and account id. 
The solution to the problem seems to be simple but I am struggling to find a clean answer.

Comment: GetAtt: returns a fixed subset of the attributes for ElastiCache and ARN is not one of them. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html#aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster-return-values 

Have you tried to accomplish the same with `!Ref` reference?

Comment: " not to be working in this case" is not clear. Why not? What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: Thanks @Mancin I edited the question so that it is bit more explanatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took inspiration from both the @multiscup answer and the [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59918221/boto3-get-elasticache-arn) referenced in the question. 
This approach is far from clean and I am waiting for a better answer but at least it is working.
The main idea is to construct the string needed for the arn:

```
arn:aws:elasticache:region:account-id:cluster:resource-name
```

To do that I used a join trying to dynamically get the element thanks to the built-in CloudFormation functions:

```
Resource: !Join 
        - ':'
        - - 'arn:aws:elasticache' 
          - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
          - '<your-account-id>'
          - 'cluster'
          - !FindInMap [Elasticache, Redis, cluster-name]
```

I used a Map to define the Redis-cluster because I was using the same value also in other points in the CloudFormation template. Maybe you might find helpful to have the map as well

```
Mappings: 
  Elasticache: 
    Redis:
      cluster-name: redis-demo
```

Answer (score 0):

As Anton mentioned, GetAtt only has certain attributes that you can get. Also, the !Ref will return the [logical ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html#cfn-elasticache-cachecluster-vpcsecuritygroupids) of the resource. Have you thought about trying to use the [User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-user.html) and/or the [UserGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-usergroup.html) resources to accomplish what you want?

Comment: it would be best if you add relevant sections from these links in the answer, in that case if these links are unavailable, we would still know what to do

Comment: You mean for example constructing the string with a join of different element like the user and so on?